# Soot get methodbodies of basic classes

Tags: java, static-analysis, soot

I wrote an small side-effect detection for java using soot. it delivers me the expected output for functions i wrote on my own. But for basic classes (java.lang.*, java.awt.*) it doesn't work.

**I want to analyse the following function with Soot:**

```
public void testMeWithSoot(){
    Point p = new Point(1,1);
    double q = Math.sqrt(p.getX() + 9);
}
```

I expect an output, that just returns the x value of the object from *java.awt.Point* but Soot delivers the following code for the **getX-function**:

```
public double getX(){ 
  java.awt.Point $r0; 
  java.lang.Error $r1; 
  $r0 :=> @this: java.awt.Point; 
  $r1 = new java.lang.Error; 
  specialinvoke $r1.<java.lang.Error: void <init>(java.lang.String)>("Unresolved
  compilation error: Method <java.awt.Point: double getX()> does not exist!");
  throw $r1; 
}
```

**I use the following code to detect side effects:**

```
public static boolean hasSideEffects(SootMethod toAnalyse){
    HashSet<SootMethod> visited = new HashSet<>();
    Stack<SootMethod> toVisit = new Stack<>();
    toVisit.add(toAnalyse);
    while (!toVisit.empty()){
        SootMethod current = toVisit.pop();
        if(visited.contains(current)) continue;
        System.out.println(current.retrieveActiveBody());
        visited.add(current);
        List<AssignStmt> assignments = current.retrieveActiveBody().getUnits().stream().filter(it -> it instanceof AssignStmt).map(it -> (AssignStmt) it).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if(assignments.stream().filter( it -> it.getLeftOp() instanceof FieldRef).findAny().orElse(null) != null){
            return true;
        }
        if(assignments.stream().filter( it -> it.getRightOp() instanceof FieldRef).findAny().orElse(null) != null){
            return true;
        }
        List<SootMethodRef> assignMethods = assignments.stream().filter(it -> it.getRightOp() instanceof InvokeExpr).map(it -> ((InvokeExpr) it.getRightOp()).getMethodRef()).collect(Collectors.toList());
        assignMethods.addAll(current.retrieveActiveBody().getUnits().stream().filter(it -> it instanceof InvokeStmt).map(it -> ((InvokeStmt) it).getInvokeExpr().getMethodRef()).collect(Collectors.toList()));


        for (SootMethodRef ref: assignMethods) {
            SootClass sootClass = bringClassToScene(ref.declaringClass().getName());
            sootClass.setApplicationClass();
            toVisit.add(ref.resolve());
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

function call:

```
classToAnalyse = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport("ToAnalyseTest");
SootMethod method = classToAnalyse.getMethod("void testMeWithSoot()");
hasSideEffects(method);
```

Do i have to load the classes manually? 
If yes, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling retrieveActiveBody() on the respective SootMethod?